# Ionic cordova build error Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath' Could not download com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework, cordova-android

I have an Ionic cordova android project that was working perfectly until last friday when I started having problems with the vpn I used, and now I can only connect using windscribe in stealth mode. This connection is really bad and because of it every time I run

> $ ionic cordova build android

I get this error

> BUILD FAILED in 1m 45s /project/platforms/android/gradlew: Command
> failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an
> exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
> > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not download builder-3.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0)
> > > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.3.0/builder-3.3.0.jar'.
> > > Connection reset

What I need to know is if there a way to solve this? Perhaps download manually this android builder and put it in some folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the point! It is really related to your internet connection, VPN or some FireWall on your network. So it can't download the dependencies to generate a build... it gets blocked because the restrictions.

Comment: Yes I know what the problem is. What I need to know is how to fix it. For example manually downloading this files and putting them somewhere. My browser connection is way better that my cli connection for some reason. So I could download all this from my browser

Comment: I know that you know, I said "You got the point!". And also I told you that is not possible to download with this restrictions. This is the correct answer! No miracles! There are a plenty of files and connections automatic to do and download on the first build, so you can't rewrite the Ionic build for do it in local. I am sorry!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I just run it many times until all the dependencies got downloaded, this will be an Issue every a few days but, at least I can work!